# Safari AppleScript - Can't Filter Tabs of Inactive Windows

Tags: safari, applescript

I've got a bit of AppleScript that is frustrating the heck out of me. I need to get a list of all Safari tabs, then filter them down. I was expecting this to be very simple. It's not.

```
tell application "Safari"
    set tabSet to {}
    repeat with w in (get every window)
        repeat with t in (get every tab of w)
            set the end of tabSet to t
        end repeat
    end repeat
    --set tabSet to every tab of every window -- a one-liner here would be convenient

    set firstTab to first item of tabSet -- works, see edit
    set targetTab to first item of tabSet whose name is "Untitled" -- this fails
end tell
```

First of all, `every tab of every window` returns a nested list of lists of tabs (grouped by window) instead of just a flat list. I just ended up going with repeats. (If there *is* a way to make this a one-liner, it would be nice). But so far, so good.

The result I was getting from `first item of tabSet` was throwing me off because it looked like it was returning a form of the entire list:

```
item 1 of {tab 1 of window id 15557 of application "Safari", tab 2 of window id 15557 of application "Safari", tab 3 of window id 15557 of application "Safari", tab 4 of...
```

The actual problem occurs on the filter line where I try to get the `first item of tabSet whose name is "Untitled"`. (Replace with a valid name of course). Then, I get this error:

```
error "Safari got an error: Can’t get tab 1 of window id 15561 whose name = \"Untitled\". Invalid index." number -1719
```

EDIT 2:

I added the following block:

```
repeat with t in tabSet
    set n to (get name of t)
    try
        set targetTab to (first item in tabSet whose name is n)
        set targetWindow to (first window whose tabs contains targetTab)
        log (get id of targetWindow) & (get name of t)
    on error
        log "ERROR: " & n
    end try
end repeat
```

This revealed that, once again, the problem was not as it seemed, but was actually something completely different:

**Only tabs in the frontmost window** can be filtered. It appears that the statement `first item of tabSet whose name is "Untitled"` fails if the tab "Untitled" is in any window other than the frontmost window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is how AppleScript refers to items from lists. You're not doing anything wrong.

When you say ‘first item’ of a list, you get ‘item 1 of {*some list*}’, that is literally equivalent to the first item in the list as you'd expect it in other languages.

All 3 of these are equivalent and refer to exactly the same thing, even though they show differently.

```
tab 1 of window id 1
```

```
item 1 of {tab 1 of window id 1}
```

```
item 1 of {tab 1 of window id 1, tab 2 of …, …}
```

You can get properties from this item as if it had never been in a list.

```
set targetName to name of targetTab -- gets the name of the tab
```

It may be confusing coming from other languages to see the entire list shown when you just want a single item, but it's likely for performance, since it doesn't attempt to extract anything from the list or even show a different representation of the item just because you don't want to see the rest of the list in some sort of output.

Comment: I see, I thought that was the issue since I couldn't filter it. It looks like the list is actually fine, but the `whose...` statement just isn't working. I've edited the question to reflect that. For some reason, `first item of tabSet whose name is "Untitled"` gives an error. I'm digging a bit more to see what else I can find.

Comment: @WhimsicalSeaplane `first item of tabSet whose name is "…"` works perfectly for me. Are you sure you have a tab with the name Untitled?

Comment: Yep, and I tried others and found that only some tabs worked, and then I started to see a pattern which I confirmed: tabs that are in a window that isn't the frontmost window will cause this error. (see edits). Now I have to find a way around that.